# Symfony Forms: split a submitted domain-name in second- and toplevel-part and save it into the model

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

first of all, sorry for the little meaningful headline. I didn't find a better one to describe the problem.

I'm working on a legacy php-application which we are migrating to symfony2 with doctrine step by step. 
We have a database-table which contains domain-names. The corresponding Toplevel-Domain (e.g. com) is also stored in this table and acts as a foreign key to a ToplevelDomain-Table.

The first problem is that the table contains the tld twice, first in the domain and second as the foreign key to the other table. I would solve this by removing the TLD from the rest of the domain.

The main Problem here is the handling of form-submissions: 
I just want to submit the whole domain-name without an extra tld-field. I guess I would have to implement a custom type and work with form-events to parse the domain-name.

Here's very simplified example:

Doctrine Model, just the relevant Parts:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ToplevelDomain")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="toplevelDomain")
 **/
private $toplevelDomain;

/**
 * Domainname without tld
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string",name="domain_name") 
 */
private $domainName;
```

Now I want to have a form field with one domain-field like this:

```
$form->add('domain');
```

The form should into the domain-name and the tld, and set both in the domain-model.

If you have any thoughts or ideas about that, I would appreciate it. I will keep digging into this and post the solution, as soon as I have one.

Thank you

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question but data transformers might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: I think that a couple of concrete examples of what you want to do would help to visualise the context of this question a bit better.

Comment: Thanks @hasumedic for the hint. I've added small code-samples.